# Broadcasting a File over WiFi, without Client App

Tags: android, android-wifi, broadcast

## Target:

Sending a file to connected peers. The connected peers should recieve the File without a preinstalled app.

## Situation - Question:

I'm writing an app that opens WiFi-direct or a WiFi-Hotspot for other devices. The other devices connect to the device (Main-Device) where the App is installed on. Now the Main-Device should broadcast a file and every device connected to the Main-Device should get a notification, that it could receive a file. But, the other devices should not need an App to receive the file!
Is this possible? Cause all I found till now describes how you can send something from one to an other device if both installed the same app. Using sockets and one device becomes server and the other client.

## Reason:

I try to create a game, which just is installed on a Main-Device. Other devices can join the game by connecting over WiFi, then they'll receive a HTML5-file from the Main-Device which they can open in their browser. As soon as they have the HTML5-file they'll be able to interact with the game on the Main-Device.
But I don't want to force everybody who likes to join the game to download the app. Another Point is, if this is possible, I don't need to rewrite the app for other systems. Cause every Smartphone/Tablet has a Browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But, the other devices should not need an App to receive the file! Is this possible?

No, it isn't.

> I try to create a game, which just is installed on a Main-Device. Other devices can join the game by connecting over WiFi

That, is possible.  What you need to do is build a captive portal.

Basically, all DNS names resolve to your server's IP address, and all traffic that would be routed elsewhere is not routed to the internet.  How you do this depends on your network setup.  There is a lot of software available.  I've used Untangle before with decent results:  https://www.untangle.com/store/captive-portal.html